# Swiper JS component flickering / not working on next js 13 app router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

i want to add a simple swiper on my nextjs website (v13 with app router) but it's giving me all types of errors.

First i tried importing it like i always do by copying it from a demo listed on their website and it was showing up fine but the navigation buttons weren't working.

So i did more research and found out they released a new version (v10) and are recommending using only the Swiper Element for all future projects but i don't understand how i'm supposed to import it on nextjs.

I tried downgrading it to v9.4.1 and repeating the usual process i've always done but now the whole component is flickering for some reason...

i don't know what to do, can anyone explain to me how to import the Swiper Element component to nextjs or help me find out why it's flickering on the older version?

here's the code for v9.4.1 with the React import:

```
"use client";
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";

import "../styles/globals.css";

// import required modules
import { Navigation } from "swiper";

export default function SwiperComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper navigation={true} modules={[Navigation]} className="mySwiper">
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 8</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 9</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}
```

this is globals.css:

```
#app {
  height: 100%;
}
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

and this is how it looks in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.6.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "eslint": "8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "hamburger-react": "^2.5.0",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "postcss": "8.4.29",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "swiper": "^9.4.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  }
}
```

this is how i'm importing it on the page:

```
<main className="text-black md:max-w-[1200px] md:m-auto bg-white font-kumbh h-screen flex flex-col pt-[110px] md:pt-auto z-[0]  relative align-middle items-center justify-center md:w-[95%]">
      <div className="flex md:flex-row flex-col md:gap-[6vw] gap-5  items-center align-middle h-fit justify-center">
        <section className="w-full md:w-1/2 z-[0] relative">
          <SwiperComponent />
        </section>
      </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `navigation` buttons didn't work because you import it wrong.
The correct one:

```
import { Navigation } from 'swiper/modules';
```